# Get last id before transaction commit using postgres in Golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I have 2 `insert` queries.

In the second `insert` query, I need the first `insert` returned `id`.

I am doing those queries as a transaction, because they depend each other.

So, is it possible to get the last insert id before committing transaction in postgres in Golang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres supports the `returning` keyword to select the inserted `id`:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2) VALUES ('Value1', 'Value2') RETURNING id;
```

Comment: i use the returning keyword. However, postgres does not insert into the table until it is commited. I commit the query at the end.

Comment: That's a common way to insert. You can rely on the value returned by returning. The new id is claimed during the insert, and will be finalized when the transaction is committed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. I thought ttransaction works in a different way: it does not insert into table and it can not return the returned id. Actually not, it works as a simple query, but it do visually.

Comment: @AibolOrazbekov: the `insert` is done **immediately**, it's just not _visible_ to other transactions until it's committed